# How do I dismiss a sheet from a child view with .onTapGesture?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this project, I am presenting a sheet called BudgetProductSheet() when a view is tapped in FavouritesView(). Inside the BudgetProductSheet I have a view called BudgetProductRow(). This produces a view of products in a HStack. Inside BudegtProductRow() I have an .onTapGesture that I want to use in order to dismiss the BudgetProductSheet(). It does not seem to be working. I have a very very similar view hierarchy and process elsewhere in my project and I successfully dismiss the sheet from an .onTapGesture {}. But for some reason it is not working here.

Here is my code: (the onTapGesture in BudgetProductRow is where I am trying the dismiss())

```
struct FavouritesView: View {
    
    @StateObject var favouritesModel = FavouriteProductsViewModel()
    @State var selectedProduct: String?
    @State var product_id: String = ""
    @State private var showingProductSheet1 = false
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(favouritesModel.favourite_products, id: \.id){ items in
            VStack {
                KFImage(URL(string: "https://domain.co.uk/product_logo/\(items.logo_file ?? "")")!)
                
                Text(String(items.product_name ?? ""))
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedProduct = ""
                selectedProduct = items.id
                product_id = items.id ?? ""
                self.showingProductSheet1 = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: Binding(
                get: { showingProductSheet1 },
                set: { showingProductSheet1 = $0 }
            ), onDismiss: {
                // Action to perform when the sheet is dismissed
                print("ON DISMISS OF FAVOURITES VIEW")
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
                self.favouritesModel.fetchFavouriteProducts(key: keyString ?? "")
            }) {
                BudgetProductSheet(product_id: $product_id)
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct BudgetProductSheet: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var marketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @Binding var product_id: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Image("Logo")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    // This dismiss() button works
                    dismiss()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                }
            }

            ForEach(marketplaceModel.budgetProducts, id:\.self){ product in
                BudgetProductRow(productData: product, product_id: $product_id)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct BudgetProductRow: View {

    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var someData = ""
    var productData: ProductTile
    @StateObject var favouritesModel = FavouriteProductsViewModel()
    @State var selectedProduct : ProductTile?
    @Binding var product_id: String


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                           ProductBudgetView(productData: productData)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    print("Tapped")
                                    someData = productData.id ?? ""
                                    selectedProduct = productData
                                    print("Product id: \(selectedProduct?.id ?? "")")
                                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                    let keyString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "key") ?? ""
                                    
                                    favouritesModel.addFavouriteProducts(key: keyString ?? "", current_id: product_id, new_id: someData,required_enviromental: "1" ) { (success) in
                                        
                                        if success {
                                            product_id = productData.id ?? ""

                                            //THIS IS THE DISMISS() THAT DOES NOT WORK
                                            dismiss()
                                            print("dismiss")

                                        } else {
                                            print("addFavouriteProducts Unsuccessful...")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would help to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you posted doesn't build.

Comment: It's possible that something in `ProductBudgetView` is "stealing" your clicks. It's also possible that clickable area is just not well defined: you can try to add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` (for example above `onTapGesture`) and see if it helps

Comment: I suspected that `dismiss()` does not propagate to subview but it seems to be working as expected in my simplified version with a similar structure. One thing I've noticed is that you call `dismiss()` in a callback, could it be possible that `favouritesModel.addFavouriteProducts()` callback is being called on a background thread?